# Not getting data from Entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony

I have a problem in Symfony (2.4.10) when I try to get data from the Entity.

Entity:

```
<?php
namespace ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class BackBill
 * @package ApiBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ApiBundle\Entity\Repository\MainRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sc_backoffice_billing")
 */
class BackBill
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_name;

/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_domi;

/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_cp;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_cif;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_dom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_cp;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_cc;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_iban;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_swift;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_logo;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_dom;

/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_cp;

/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_cif;

/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $incr;

public function __construct($values = null)
{
    $this->setValues($values);
}

public function setValues($values)
{
    $this->id = (isset($values['id']))?$values['id'] : null;
    $this->cli_name = (isset($values['cli_name']))?$values['cli_name'] : null;
    $this->cli_domi = (isset($values['cli_domi']))?$values['cli_domi'] : null;
    $this->cli_cp = (isset($values['cli_cp']))?$values['cli_cp'] : null;
    $this->cli_cif = (isset($values['cli_cif']))?$values['cli_cif'] : null;
    $this->ban_name = (isset($values['ban_name']))?$values['ban_name'] : null;
    $this->ban_dom = (isset($values['ban_dom']))?$values['ban_dom'] : null;
    $this->ban_cp = (isset($values['ban_cp']))?$values['ban_cp'] : null;
    $this->ban_cc = (isset($values['ban_cc']))?$values['ban_cc'] : null;
    $this->ban_iban = (isset($values['ban_iban']))?$values['ban_iban'] : null;
    $this->ban_swift = (isset($values['ban_swift']))?$values['ban_swift'] : null;
    $this->sc_logo = (isset($values['sc_logo']))?$values['sc_logo'] : null;
    $this->sc_name = (isset($values['sc_name']))?$values['sc_name'] : null;
    $this->sc_dom = (isset($values['sc_dom']))?$values['sc_dom'] : null;
    $this->sc_cp = (isset($values['sc_cp']))?$values['sc_cp'] : null;
    $this->sc_cif = (isset($values['sc_cif']))?$values['sc_cif'] : null;
    $this->incr = (isset($values['incr']))?$values['incr'] : null;
}

public function updateValues($values)
{
    if(isset($values['id'])) $this->id = $values['id'];
    if(isset($values['cli_name'])) $this->cli_name = $values['cli_name'];
    if(isset($values['cli_domi'])) $this->cli_domi = $values['cli_domi'];
    if(isset($values['cli_cp'])) $this->cli_cp = $values['cli_cp'];
    if(isset($values['cli_cif'])) $this->cli_cif = $values['cli_cif'];
    if(isset($values['ban_name'])) $this->ban_name = $values['ban_name'];
    if(isset($values['ban_dom'])) $this->ban_dom = $values['ban_dom'];
    if(isset($values['ban_cp'])) $this->ban_cp = $values['ban_cp'];
    if(isset($values['ban_cc'])) $this->ban_cc = $values['ban_cc'];
    if(isset($values['ban_iban'])) $this->ban_iban = $values['ban_iban'];
    if(isset($values['ban_swift'])) $this->ban_swift = $values['ban_swift'];
    if(isset($values['sc_logo'])) $this->sc_logo = $values['sc_logo'];
    if(isset($values['sc_name'])) $this->sc_name = $values['sc_name'];
    if(isset($values['sc_dom'])) $this->sc_dom = $values['sc_dom'];
    if(isset($values['sc_cp'])) $this->sc_cp = $values['sc_cp'];
    if(isset($values['sc_cif'])) $this->sc_cif = $values['sc_cif'];
    if(isset($values['incr'])) $this->incr = $values['incr'];
}

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getCli_name() {
    return $this->cli_name;
}

public function getCliDom() {
    return $this->cli_domi;
}

function getCli_cp() {
    return $this->cli_cp;
}

function getCli_cif() {
    return $this->cli_cif;
}

function getBan_name() {
    return $this->ban_name;
}

function getBan_dom() {
    return $this->ban_dom;
}

function getBan_cp() {
    return $this->ban_cp;
}

function getBan_cc() {
    return $this->ban_cc;
}

function getBan_iban() {
    return $this->ban_iban;
}

function getBan_swift() {
    return $this->ban_swift;
}

function getSc_logo() {
    return $this->sc_logo;
}

function getSc_name() {
    return $this->sc_name;
}

function getSc_dom() {
    return $this->sc_dom;
}

function getSc_cp() {
    return $this->sc_cp;
}

function getSc_cif() {
    return $this->sc_cif;
}

function getIncr() {
    return $this->incr;
}

function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

function setCli_name($cli_name) {
    $this->cli_name = $cli_name;
}

public function setCliDom($cli_domi) {
    $this->cli_domi = $cli_domi;
}

function setCli_cp($cli_cp) {
    $this->cli_cp = $cli_cp;
}

function setCli_cif($cli_cif) {
    $this->cli_cif = $cli_cif;
}

function setBan_name($ban_name) {
    $this->ban_name = $ban_name;
}

function setBan_dom($ban_dom) {
    $this->ban_dom = $ban_dom;
}

function setBan_cp($ban_cp) {
    $this->ban_cp = $ban_cp;
}

function setBan_cc($ban_cc) {
    $this->ban_cc = $ban_cc;
}

function setBan_iban($ban_iban) {
    $this->ban_iban = $ban_iban;
}

function setBan_swift($ban_swift) {
    $this->ban_swift = $ban_swift;
}

function setSc_logo($sc_logo) {
    $this->sc_logo = $sc_logo;
}

function setSc_name($sc_name) {
    $this->sc_name = $sc_name;
}

function setSc_dom($sc_dom) {
    $this->sc_dom = $sc_dom;
}

function setSc_cp($sc_cp) {
    $this->sc_cp = $sc_cp;
}

function setSc_cif($sc_cif) {
    $this->sc_cif = $sc_cif;
}

function setIncr($incr) {
    $this->incr = $incr;
}
```

The Getters and Setters are very well created and the database have good conection.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `sc_backoffice_billing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cli_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cli_domi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cli_cp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cli_cif` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_dom` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_cp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_cc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_iban` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ban_swift` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sc_logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sc_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sc_dom` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sc_cp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sc_cif` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incr` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Controller:

```
public function configAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user_repo = $em->getRepository("ApiBundle:BackBill");
    $dataBill = $user_repo->find(1);

    return $this->render(
        'ApiBundle:backoffice:configFact.html.twig',
        array(
            'billing' => $dataBill,

        )
    );

}
```

Then I have the controller that renders the view for the selected entity.

But when it renders, some data from the entity send null, but in the Table it has a value:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php:56:
object(ApiBundle\Entity\BackBill)[350]
  protected 'id' => int 1
  protected 'cli_name' => string 'some data' (length=5)
  protected 'cli_domi' => null
  protected 'cli_cp' => null
  protected 'cli_cif' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'ban_name' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'ban_dom' => string 'some data' (length=5)
  protected 'ban_cp' => string 'some data' (length=15)
  protected 'ban_cc' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'ban_iban' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'ban_swift' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'sc_logo' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'sc_name' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'sc_dom' => string 'some data' (length=3)
  protected 'sc_cp' => null
  protected 'sc_cif' => null
  protected 'incr' => null
```

I checked the twig, but it's sensitive if any code there it's wrong named.

I don't know how to resolve this...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you checked that your values are existing in $premRes, so after fetching it from DB but before rendering?

Comment: I did it @LBA and I have 'nulls' there...

Comment: so then this cannot be related to twig for sure. and you say, your Object BackBill with id=1 has all value in table sc_backoffice_billing with id=1?

Comment: Yes @LBA It's setted and applied with id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I did wrong...

Simply I just created the Entities from scratch and in that code just remains an * in the entity archive.

```
<?php
namespace ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class BackBill
 * @package ApiBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ApiBundle\Entity\Repository\MainRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sc_backoffice_billing")
 */
class BackBill
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_domi;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_cp;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $cli_cif;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_dom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_cp;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_cc;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_iban;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $ban_swift;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_logo;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_dom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_cp;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $sc_cif;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $incr;

public function __construct($values = null)
{
    $this->setValues($values);
}

public function setValues($values)
{
    $this->id = (isset($values['id']))?$values['id'] : null;
    $this->cli_name = (isset($values['cli_name']))?$values['cli_name'] :     null;
    $this->cli_domi = (isset($values['cli_domi']))?$values['cli_domi'] : null;
    $this->cli_cp = (isset($values['cli_cp']))?$values['cli_cp'] : null;
    $this->cli_cif = (isset($values['cli_cif']))?$values['cli_cif'] : null;
    $this->ban_name = (isset($values['ban_name']))?$values['ban_name'] : null;
    $this->ban_dom = (isset($values['ban_dom']))?$values['ban_dom'] : null;
    $this->ban_cp = (isset($values['ban_cp']))?$values['ban_cp'] : null;
    $this->ban_cc = (isset($values['ban_cc']))?$values['ban_cc'] : null;
    $this->ban_iban = (isset($values['ban_iban']))?$values['ban_iban'] : null;
    $this->ban_swift = (isset($values['ban_swift']))?$values['ban_swift'] : null;
    $this->sc_logo = (isset($values['sc_logo']))?$values['sc_logo'] : null;
    $this->sc_name = (isset($values['sc_name']))?$values['sc_name'] : null;
    $this->sc_dom = (isset($values['sc_dom']))?$values['sc_dom'] : null;
    $this->sc_cp = (isset($values['sc_cp']))?$values['sc_cp'] : null;
    $this->sc_cif = (isset($values['sc_cif']))?$values['sc_cif'] : null;
    $this->incr = (isset($values['incr']))?$values['incr'] : null;
}

public function updateValues($values)
{
    if(isset($values['id'])) $this->id = $values['id'];
    if(isset($values['cli_name'])) $this->cli_name = $values['cli_name'];
    if(isset($values['cli_domi'])) $this->cli_domi = $values['cli_domi'];
    if(isset($values['cli_cp'])) $this->cli_cp = $values['cli_cp'];
    if(isset($values['cli_cif'])) $this->cli_cif = $values['cli_cif'];
    if(isset($values['ban_name'])) $this->ban_name = $values['ban_name'];
    if(isset($values['ban_dom'])) $this->ban_dom = $values['ban_dom'];
    if(isset($values['ban_cp'])) $this->ban_cp = $values['ban_cp'];
    if(isset($values['ban_cc'])) $this->ban_cc = $values['ban_cc'];
    if(isset($values['ban_iban'])) $this->ban_iban = $values['ban_iban'];
    if(isset($values['ban_swift'])) $this->ban_swift = $values['ban_swift'];
    if(isset($values['sc_logo'])) $this->sc_logo = $values['sc_logo'];
    if(isset($values['sc_name'])) $this->sc_name = $values['sc_name'];
    if(isset($values['sc_dom'])) $this->sc_dom = $values['sc_dom'];
    if(isset($values['sc_cp'])) $this->sc_cp = $values['sc_cp'];
    if(isset($values['sc_cif'])) $this->sc_cif = $values['sc_cif'];
    if(isset($values['incr'])) $this->incr = $values['incr'];
}

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getCli_name() {
    return $this->cli_name;
}

public function getCliDom() {
    return $this->cli_domi;
}

function getCli_cp() {
    return $this->cli_cp;
}

function getCli_cif() {
    return $this->cli_cif;
}

function getBan_name() {
    return $this->ban_name;
}

function getBan_dom() {
    return $this->ban_dom;
}

function getBan_cp() {
    return $this->ban_cp;
}

function getBan_cc() {
    return $this->ban_cc;
}

function getBan_iban() {
    return $this->ban_iban;
}

function getBan_swift() {
    return $this->ban_swift;
}

function getSc_logo() {
    return $this->sc_logo;
}

function getSc_name() {
    return $this->sc_name;
}

function getSc_dom() {
    return $this->sc_dom;
}

function getSc_cp() {
    return $this->sc_cp;
}

function getSc_cif() {
    return $this->sc_cif;
}

function getIncr() {
    return $this->incr;
}

function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

function setCli_name($cli_name) {
    $this->cli_name = $cli_name;
}

public function setCliDom($cli_domi) {
    $this->cli_domi = $cli_domi;
}

function setCli_cp($cli_cp) {
    $this->cli_cp = $cli_cp;
}

function setCli_cif($cli_cif) {
    $this->cli_cif = $cli_cif;
}

function setBan_name($ban_name) {
    $this->ban_name = $ban_name;
}

function setBan_dom($ban_dom) {
    $this->ban_dom = $ban_dom;
}

function setBan_cp($ban_cp) {
    $this->ban_cp = $ban_cp;
}

function setBan_cc($ban_cc) {
    $this->ban_cc = $ban_cc;
}

function setBan_iban($ban_iban) {
    $this->ban_iban = $ban_iban;
}

function setBan_swift($ban_swift) {
    $this->ban_swift = $ban_swift;
}

function setSc_logo($sc_logo) {
    $this->sc_logo = $sc_logo;
}

function setSc_name($sc_name) {
    $this->sc_name = $sc_name;
}

function setSc_dom($sc_dom) {
    $this->sc_dom = $sc_dom;
}

function setSc_cp($sc_cp) {
    $this->sc_cp = $sc_cp;
}

function setSc_cif($sc_cif) {
    $this->sc_cif = $sc_cif;
}

function setIncr($incr) {
    $this->incr = $incr;
}
```

Beware with the sintax with Symfony Entity Creation, something the problem is very silly..